# Chat: How do I get to it?

Tags: support, faq, chat, chat-faq

I keep seeing people say in comments

> 'let's take this to chat'

or

> 'this would be better in chat'

But I don't know how to get to there.

I've looked all over the FAQ and it mentions chat but I don't see the link.

How do I get to chat?

Comment: Good question and equally good answer, but to find this 'how to' guide, a user has to find Meta, now where do I find meta? Yes Meta has more visibility with the side-bar block 'Featured on Meta' on most pages, can we have a link to meta and chat in the top bar visible at all times, without negotiating the drop-down.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're right to want to come to chat. It's a wonderful place where lots of great and constructive discussion happens.

To find your way to chat you'll have to look at the top of the site, to the left of where your avatar is:

[image: highlighted stack exchange logo]

There you'll see the Stack Exchange logo. Click on that and a menu will appear.

[image: Stack Exchange Menu]

I have highlighted there the link to chat. Click on that and you will be transported to here:

[image: list of chat rooms]

This is the list of chat rooms. The first in the list, as it's shown there, is the one you're most likely to want to visit, that's the English Language & Usage main room, called English Language & Usage.

It's worth noting that the rooms are ordered by activity, so sometimes a different room will be first in the list, but mostly not.

Be sure to read the [chat FAQ](http://chat.stackexchange.com/faq) and the [chat help](http://chat.stackexchange.com/help) before you start chatting, to familiarise yourself with how it works.

Comment: You might need to update the info or wait further until the proposed left navigator thingy is imposed network wide.